# Symfony Batch Action

Tags: symfony1, batch-file, zip

I'm trying to create a batch action (symfony admin) that enables the creation/download on the fly of zip file containing users photos which are avaialable on the uploads/images directory.

Here is the code that I already implemented:

```
public function executeBatchDownloadFotos(sfWebRequest $request)
    {
        $zip = new ZipArchive();

        // atheletes identifiers
        $ids = $request->getParameter('ids');

        // get all the atheletes objects
        $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('Atleta a')
            ->whereIn('a.id', $ids);

        foreach ($q->execute() as $atleta)
        {
            $zip->addFile($atleta->id . '_' . $atleta->Clube . '.jpg', 'uploads/atletas/' . $atleta->id . '_' . $atleta->Clube . '.jpg');
        }
    }
```

By the other hand, here is the view configuration:

```
BatchDownloadFotos:
  http_metas:
    content-type: application/zip
  has_layout:     false
```

For some reason, each time execute the batch action, the browser do not prompts me with the window to download the zip file.

Answer (score 2):

After you create ZIP archive in your controller file you should send the content to the browser.

You can do this using methods described here: http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_sub_action_termination

Now you are trying to create ZIP file, but you are not sending it to the browser. You should use *setContent*() and *setHttpHeader*() methods.

Your action could look like this (you should add error handling):

```
public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $fileName = '/tmp/test.zip';
  $zip = new ZipArchive();

  $zip->open($fileName, ZipArchive::CREATE);

  // add some files to archive
  $zip->addFile('/tmp/test', 'test.txt');

  $zip->close();

  $this->getResponse()->setContent(file_get_contents($fileName));
  $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/zip');
  $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Disposition',
    'attachment; filename=download.zip');

  return sfView::NONE;
}
```

Comment: Hi there!

What should I place inside the setHttpHeader() method?

Thanks for the help!
Best regards!

Comment: You should set name and value of HTTP header: http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfWebResponse#method_sethttpheader. So, in your case it should be "Content-Type" and "application/zip". You should also set "Content-Disposition" header: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition

Comment: Hi there!

Running your code, I have noticed that the test.zip file is not created in the /tmp/ directory.

Any idea why this problem is occurring?

Thanks for all the help,
Best regards!

Comment: Check if you have loaded zip extension. You can run 'php -m' command or use phpinfo() function.